# How to pass Font's parameters from PyQt dialog widget to reportlab?

Tags: python, fonts, pyqt, reportlab

I need to get font parameters for pdf output (reportlab can receive path to file containing the font), using PyQt (QFontDialog), but PyQt has an internal representation (QFont), which reportlab can not embed into pdf output.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What are the required "font parameters"? Can you give an example? Also, what platform(s) does this have to work on?

Comment: Running on WinXP (64bit).

That's how I get font using standard dialog (PyQt):


    font, ok = QtGui.QFontDialog.getFont()  

But here I need to pass as parameter path to desired font (reportlab):


    #Should be a path to file with font  
    font_to_embed = "C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\Upclbi.ttf"  
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("Font1", font_to_embed))  

How can I determine, what is font file from the Qt Font Dialog?

Comment: Qt does not provide any way to retrieve the path of a font file. So you will have to either roll your own solution (e.g. by scanning the windows registry), or perhaps look for a third-party tool.